# Text over the tint over an image in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have made a screen where in the background there is an image and over it is a tint colour.

Now i have to write some text over that image.

When i do that the tint comes over the text but i want the text above the image and tint.

My XML is this

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/batball"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:foreground="@color/tintColorPrimary"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <!--<ImageView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:src="@drawable/batball"-->
                <!--android:scaleType="centerCrop"-->
                <!--android:backgroundTint="@color/tintColorPrimary"/>-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{dashboardVm.teamA.teamShortName}"
                    android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/team_playing_font_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    bind:imageUrl="@{dashboardVm.teamA.imageUrl}"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"

                    />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="VS"
                        android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/team_playing_font_size"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@{dashboardVm.teamB.teamShortName}"
                        android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/team_playing_font_size"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                        />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        bind:imageUrl="@{dashboardVm.teamB.imageUrl}"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/match_countdown"
                    android:text="Match start in 24 : 20 :39"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screen with my code]

The screen looks like this though i want it like the following one:

[image: Screen like i want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the parent linear layout with Framelayout and in the imageview i put image and set tint as the tintColour.

```
            <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/batball"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:tint="@color/tintColorPrimary"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{dashboardVm.teamA.teamShortName}"
                    android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/team_playing_font_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    bind:imageUrl="@{dashboardVm.teamA.imageUrl}"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"

                    />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="VS"
                        android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/team_playing_font_size"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@{dashboardVm.teamB.teamShortName}"
                        android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/team_playing_font_size"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                        />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        bind:imageUrl="@{dashboardVm.teamB.imageUrl}"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/match_countdown"
                    android:text="Match start in 24 : 20 :39"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
android:foreground="@color/tintColorPrimary"
```

on the root LinearLayout

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:foreground):

> android:foreground
>
> Defines the drawable to draw over the content. This
>   can be used as an overlay. The foreground drawable participates in the
>   padding of the content if the gravity is set to fill.

So basically you tint colour is applied over everything contained in the LinearLayout, including the texts.

What happens if you uncomment the ImageView? Is it not working, as I'd suggest something like that? But in that case you need to use a `RelativeLayout` as root if you want the image to take the entire screen.

**EDIT**

Try something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <!-- Background image -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/tintColorPrimary"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/batball" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/you_name_it_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
            android:text="@{dashboardVm.teamA.teamShortName}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/team_playing_font_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
            bind:imageUrl="@{dashboardVm.teamA.imageUrl}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
            android:text="VS"
            android:textSize="@dimen/team_playing_font_size" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
            android:text="@{dashboardVm.teamB.teamShortName}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/team_playing_font_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/playing_team_padding"
            bind:imageUrl="@{dashboardVm.teamB.imageUrl}" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/match_countdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/you_name_it_ll"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        tools:text="Match start in 24 : 20 :39" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When i use imageview the text just disappears or maybe it goes in the background and i cannot apply tint either. I think the linear layout is causing the problem and mabe FrameLayout will help but i am confused.

Comment: You can't use a LinearLayout with an ImageView in this case. A LinearLayout piles its children so if the ImageView takes the entire screen, the rest will be displayed outside of it so you'll not see them. Use a RelativeLayout or a ConstraintLayout

Comment: I figured it out. I used the imageview and used FramLayout and and used tint property in imageview to set the colour and it's done. Thanks for the comment to show me a direction.

Comment: I've added an example (I haven't tested so maybe there are a few issues)

Comment: Btw, use `tools:text=` instead of `android:text` when you want to display text placeholders for design purpose